# Arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gematria of Mi Yodeya

Comment: Good one! Checkmark because I can't resist.

Answer (score 6):

Abraham's age when Yitzhak got married  (Yitzhak was 40 when he married Rivka. [בראשית כ"ה, כ](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0125.htm#20))

Answer (score 4):

The number of years Job lived after his "troubles". ([Job 42:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2742.htm#16))

Answer (score 3):

According to [*B'rachos* 55 *amud* 1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=107&size=1), *Yosef* was the first to die among *Yaakov*'s sons. From *Yosef*'s death (at 110 after [he'd been born when *Yitzchak* was 151](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816193605/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html), so 261 years into the 400-year exile) until the second year of travel through the desert was 140 years. That's the period described in the book of *Sh'mos*: from the death of *Yosef*, his brothers, and "that entire generation" until the *mishkan* was erected.

Answer (score 2):

Chanukah happened in 140 BCE